# Have bloodstream nanobots been approved in any countries?

Tags: microcontroller

A Google search on "bloodstream nanobots" yields thousands of results and just on the first page, many results of blog posts that date back to 2009. It is nearly 4 years later.

I've had no luck in finding any information on actual APPROVAL of these bots.

Are there any countries at all who have approved this? People seem to have talked about it like crazy 4 years ago, yet, we're still not seeing anything.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: No.

While there is a lot of media hype, and patent applications, there isn't any nanobots being commercially manufactured. Its unlikely that any legislative or FDA approval would happen before there are working demonstration models of actual utility.
There are several significant problems that have to be solved before we see any kind of production models: a lack of nanoscale processors and dependable nanoscale power supplies probably being the two biggest problems.

I would estimate 20+ years before they become mainstream.